# C# service to run on Windows 10 IoT

Tags: pi-2, windows-iot, services

I've developed a Windows based service, is it possible to install the service to Windows 10 IoT? If YES, please state how. TQ

P/S: I'm using PI-2 model B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is No.

If you want to try stuff out then, for a long time you could not install background services or applications. Things are slowly changing though but still very slowly tricking in.

You can have a look at [this merge in GitHub](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/pull/119/files) on how to get service running on the Windows PIoT. I am sorry but it does not look like a simple command yet, like you would use service install on the desktop. But that merge provides a service framework and has been merged into the development branch. There is [more info here](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/issues/65) about the merge but it looks like its for C++ services only.

The architectural way of Windows IoT on the Pi is to write one UWP application. That application can then spawn off background processes as the front end keeps working. This is due to the design of the OS and how it sandboxes every process.